# after filling and updating my custom fields nothing shows in the update in wordpress

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Im using ACF to create custom fields which are 3 types : image/ text/ Wysiwyg Editor, i go to the page which contains those fields after filling them with the contents & update the page nothing changes except for the image which is been inserted successfully [after filling nothing appears and fields got empty again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JV3e.png)

so here's how i get the fields from my code

```
   $who_section_image          = get_field('who_section_image');
     $who_section_title         = get_field('who_section_title');
     $who_section_body          = get_field('who_section_body');
```

after that here is how i display it in the page [image: display code]

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the amount of php max variables your hosting service provides. Each field on a page will sent 22 variables, and with other things combined can still stack up.

I would recommend increasing your PHP max vars to 5000.

This can be done in the php.ini file, your htaccess file or in plesk php settings.

**PHP.INI**

```
max_input_vars = 5000;
```

**HTACCESS:**

```
php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000
```

**Plesk:**

Domain > PHP Settings > max_execution_time > 5000

Comment: Well i'm still having the problem even when i modified the max_input_vars from my php.ini
for the htaccess i've found different statements for giving access and i'm not familliar to it so i didn't change it at all.
btw i'm still on my localhost (wampserver) so there is no plesk php i guess

Comment: In that case you will have to go into the php.ini, for the specific PHP version you're using in WAMP. Sometimes its difficult to find, make a file called phpinfo.php and put <?php phpinfo();?> in there to see if the max vars has gone up.  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,86111

Comment: i did it already and 've checked phpinfo it increased to the amount i did but i still have that problem, i guess maybe the problem is from advanced custom field version who is not compatible yet with the wordpress ver 4.9.2

Comment: Not quite sure on this then. Have you checked the page meta_keys to make sure they're being submitted to the database ready for displaying? I know its compatible as I'm using it.

Comment: i've checked with a previous version of wordpress and still the problem is presistent, when i see the preview changes the fields shows up but when i update the page things get erased again !!

Comment: i don't know how to check it could you give me some hint where i can check it and how ?